# Using rep inside sapply to strech a vector according to another vector

Tags: r, apply, sapply

I want to generate a `data.frame` of edges. Problems arise when many edges end on one node. Edges are defined in vectors `from` and `to`.

```
# Data
vertices <- data.frame(id = 1:3, label = c("a", "b", "c"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
to <- c("a", "b", "c")
from1 <- c("c", "a", "b")
from2 <- c("c", "a", "a,b,c")
```

What I tried:

```
# Attempt 1
create_edges_1 <- function(from, to) {
  to <- sapply(to, function(x){vertices$id[vertices$label == x]})
  from <- sapply(from, function(x){vertices$id[vertices$label == x]})
  data.frame(from = from, to = to, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

This works for example `create_edges_1(from1, to)`, the output is:

```
  from to
c    3  1
a    1  2
b    2  3
```

However for example `from2` this attempt fails.

So I tried the following:

```
# Attempt 2
create_edges_2 <- function(from, to) {
  to <- sapply(unlist(sapply(strsplit(to, ","), function(x){vertices$id[vertices$label == x]})), function(x){rep(x, sapply(strsplit(from2, ","), length))})
  from <- unlist(sapply(strsplit(from2, ","), function(x){vertices$id[vertices$label == x]}))
  data.frame(from = from, to = to, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

The idea was to "stretch" `to` for every node where more than one edge ends. However `create_edges_2(from1, to)` and `create_edges_2(from2, to)` both throw an error

> Error in rep(x, sapply(strsplit(from2, ","), length)) : 
>     invalid 'times' argument

What am I doing wrong in my `sapply` statements?

The expected output for `create_edges_2(from2, to)` is:

```
  from to
     3  1
     1  2
     1  3
     2  3
     3  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use joins or `match` for this

```
f2 <- strsplit(from2, ',')

df <- data.frame(from = unlist(f2)
                 , to = rep(to, lengths(f2))
                 , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

With `match`

```
library(tidyverse)

map_dfc(df, ~ with(vertices, id[match(.x, label)]))

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#    from    to
#   <int> <int>
# 1     3     1
# 2     1     2
# 3     1     3
# 4     2     3
# 5     3     3
```

With Joins

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  inner_join(vertices, by = c(from = 'label')) %>% 
  inner_join(vertices, by = c(to = 'label')) %>% 
  select_at(vars(matches('.x|.y')))

#   id.x id.y
# 1    3    1
# 2    1    2
# 3    1    3
# 4    2    3
# 5    3    3
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the `lengths` function. The `rep(to, lengths(from))` part was the missing link in my head. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
# Attempt 3
library(dplyr)
to <- sapply(to, function(x){vertices$id[vertices$label == x]})
from0 <- sapply(from2, function(x) strsplit(x, ",")) %>% unlist() %>% as.character()
lengths0 <- lapply(sapply(from2, function(x) strsplit(x, ",")), length) %>% unlist()

to0 <- c()
for( i in 1:length(lengths0)) to0 <- c(to0, rep(to[i], lengths0[i]))

from <- sapply(from0, function(x){vertices$id[vertices$label == x]})
edges <- data.frame(from = from, to = to0, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
edges
```

Giving this result as requested:

```
  from to
1    3  1
2    1  2
3    1  3
4    2  3
5    3  3
```

The idea is to split `from` with comma separators, and to store the size of each element in order to "stretch" every node. Here done with a `for` loop